# How to prepend additional text to options in select box

Tags: jquery, html

I have a project creating select boxes for a client. But he is asking for something I'm not familiar with. Basically for every option in the select box he wants to add additional text to it. For example if this option is selected: `<option value="all">all</option>` it would come out like this "**category: all**". I am able to change the first option that is selected but I need to be able to change each option when it gets selected from the dropdown. I believe Im close to the solution, just missing something. Most likely a change function. Any suggestions would be appreciated
jquery

```
$(function () {
    var selected = $('#selectBox');
    var optionName = $(selected).find("option:selected").text();
    $(selected).find("option:selected").html('<span>category:</span> '+optionName+'');
    console.log(selected);
});
```

html

```
 <select id="selectBox" name="selectBox">
                         <option value="all">all</option>
                         <option value="milk">milk</option>
                         <option value="frozen">frozen</option>
                         <option value="cream">cream</option>
                         <option value="sour-cream">sour cream</option>
                         <option value="cottage-cheese">cottage cheese</option>
                         <option value="eggnog">eggnog</option>
                         <option value="calorie-counter">calorie countdown</option>
                         <option value="juices-drinks">juices & drinks</option>
                         <option value="simply-smart">simply smart</option>
                         <option value="our-farmers">our farmers</option>
                     </select>
```

Comment: You can't add any HTML to an `option` element; it can *only* contain text.

Comment: Why would you do this the unreliable way, with client-side scripting, instead of having the desired `value` attribute in HTML source?

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest:

```
// select the select elements (amend to your use-case)
$('select')
// binding an anonymous function as an event handler to the 'change' event:
.on('change', function(){
    // this is the 'select' element
    $(this)
    // find the 'option' elements inside that select:
    .find('option')
    // iterating over each element within the 'text()' method:
    .text(function(i,t){
        // i: is the index of the current element,
        // t: is the current text (before manipulation)
        // if the current option is 'selected' we prepend the text with 'Category: '
        // if not, we remove 'Category: ' (if it's there)
        return this.selected ? 'Category: ' + t : t.replace('Category: ', '');
    });
// trigger the change event, causing the handler to fire (so 'Category: ' is
// prepended to the default-shown 'option' text on page-load:
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5fugz/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Sorry for the off topic but just wondering, are you setting link references manually or using a tool for that?

Comment: No problem at all :) I do it manually, which for jQuery references is particularly easy (it's *always* `http://api.jquery.com/methodName/`), for the non-jQuery references it's *still* manually, but it usually involves my browser history and/or Google.

Comment: @user: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand the question you're asking? It'll fire every time the value is changed, yes, and once on page-load/DOMReady; but otherwise no.

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry I inadvertently deleted my question but see this demo to understand what I mean: the `change` callback is invoked 11 (size of select list) times for every select: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/5fugz/1/) ---> Question was "I may be mistaken but won't the `change` event fire repeatedly?"

Comment: Thanks you, it works great, but the issue is Im using this plugin for the select box: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/index.html If I disable the plugin it works. How can I work around that?

Comment: @user: yes, what you're proving there is that every time the `change()` method responds to the `change` *event* the `text()` method iterates over each of the (11) `option` elements. Which I stated, or at least *implied* in the explanation of the code in the answer. The `change()` method is triggered precisely *once* (on page-load/DOMReady) and once again each time a different `option` is selected: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5fugz/2/).

Comment: @jmccommas: I have no idea, but I'd suggest adding that information to your question and posting a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your own in order to demonstrate what, precisely, is going on and what you're doing. Also add the relevant (minimal/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code to your question.

Comment: @DavidThomas you can avoid having to look at every single option by simply using `option:selected` as I have suggested. [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/5fugz/3/). All other discussions aside, it's an awesome answer!

Comment: Yes, I know; but selecting only the `option:selected` elements means the `'Category: '` string is *never removed* from unselected `<option>`s.